# .NET DirectoryInfo.GetFiles with wildcard bahaves differently on different drives

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winapi, ntfs

I have encountered a very strange bug in DirectoryInfo.GetFiles("*.xls").

I have a directory zzz on drive C, that contains 2 files: File1.xls and File2.xlsx.

When I call GetFiles("*.xls") it returns 2 files as stated in the documentation:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms143327(v=vs.110).aspx

They have exactly the same wildcard example there. And I have read about this backward compatibility "smart solution" to make 3-letter extensions behave differently from other extensions.

BUT, when I call it for the same folder on drive D (a copy with all the files), it returns 1 file! And I don't understand why.

Both C and D are formatted as NTFS. The drive D is a recovery drive created by laptop vendor (and also formatted as NTFS) on the same hard disk. The only difference I can see is that D is not primary logical drive.

When I tried same on a FAT32 formatted flash drive and NTFS formatted external HDD it returns 2 files.

Can anyone else reproduce this? I made a workaround (use GetFiles() and then filter by extension) that helps, but it is interesting if this is a .net bug, Windows bug or something else.

I tried this on Windows 10 x64 and .net 4.5.2.

Comment: Did you check the file permissions and attributes  (e.g. 'hidden')?

Comment: What they're neglecting to tell you is that 8.3 filename creation can be disabled on NTFS drives -- for all drives, all but the system drive, or per-volume (default). I assume it's using the default per-volume setting and your recovery drive has this disabled. You can check via `fsutil behavior query Disable8dot3 D:`.

Comment: Yes, you are right! It is enabled for C and disabled for D! Microsoft crutches as always...